# Pandas: growing a series backwards using growth rate of another series

Tags: python, pandas

I have missing data at the start of a DataFrame for one series, and I want to fill those NAs by growing back the series using the growth rate of another.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 6, 6.7, 6.78, 7, 9.1], 
                   'Y':[5.4, 5.7, 5.5, 6.1, 6.5, 6.80, 7.1, 9.12]})

      X     Y
0   NaN  5.40
1   NaN  5.70
2   NaN  5.50
3  6.00  6.10
4  6.70  6.50
5  6.78  6.80
6  7.00  7.10
7  9.10  9.12
```

i.e. what I want is:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[5.31147, 5.60656, 5.40984, 6, 6.7, 6.78, 7, 9.1], 
                   'Y':[5.4, 5.7, 5.5, 6.1, 6.5, 6.80, 7.1, 9.12]})
```

So that the two series have the same growth rates for those first few original missing values

```
df2.pct_change()

          X         Y
0       NaN       NaN
1  0.055556  0.055556
2 -0.035088 -0.035088
3  0.109091  0.109091
4  0.116667  0.065574
5  0.011940  0.046154
6  0.032448  0.044118
7  0.300000  0.284507
```

Any ideas? I've figured out how to iterate back and save the output to a list, but pre-pending it's bulky and I need to prepend it to the original DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

You could let

```
first_non_nan = df.X.isnull().idxmin()
changes = df.Y[:first_non_nan+1].pct_change()
while first_non_nan > 0:
    df.X[first_non_nan-1] = df.X[first_non_nan]/(changes[first_non_nan]+1)
    first_non_nan -= 1
```

Result:

```
In [48]: df
Out[48]:
          X     Y
0  5.311475  5.40
1  5.606557  5.70
2  5.409836  5.50
3  6.000000  6.10
4  6.700000  6.50
5  6.780000  6.80
6  7.000000  7.10
7  9.100000  9.12
```